# Show that $P(X=-1)=p$ and $P(X=k)=q^2 p^k$, $k=0,1,2,...$ defines a probability distribution for the random variable $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

Let $p \in (0,1)$ and $q=1-p$.

(a) Show that $P(X=-1)=p$ and $P(X=k)=q^2 p^k$, $k=0,1,2,...$ defines a probability distribution for the random variable $X$. (proved)

(b) Given the single observation $X$, the statistic $X$ is sufficient; is $X$ also complete?

**Progress:** I want to apply the definition of being complete and sufficient statistic, i.e. if $E(X)=0$, then we should have $P(X=0)=1$. Here if $E(X)=0$, then we know the observation is just zero, so the probability is 1.

(c)Determine all unbiased estimators of $p$, given one observation of $X$ from the family above.

**Progress:** We know $T(X)=\mathbb 1_{\{X=-1\}}$ is an unbiased estimator. I don't know how to decide all the unbiased estimators.

(d) Find the UMVUE of $p$, or prove that it does not exist.

Comment: Actually,
$$E(X)=-p+q^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty kp^k = -p + q^2 p \sum_{k=0}^\infty kp^{k-1} = -p + q^2 p \frac{1}{(1-p)^2} = 0$$
no matter what $p$ is. So this random variable always has expectation zero, but need not be zero almost surely.

Comment: @angryavian I see. So you mean $X$ is not necessarily complete, right?

Comment: I think angryavian wanted to point out that your argument does not work here. Concluding that $X$ (single observation) is zero if $E(X)=0$ is correct but does not proof completeness. For this purpose you have to show that if $E(g(X))=0\ \forall p\in (0,1)$ then $g\equiv 0$.